# Pytorch vectors with empty dimensions

Tags: python, vector, deep-learning, pytorch

I noticed that some vectors in pytorch have empty dimensions like `a=torch.randn(1)` has size `(1L,)`. What are these types of vectors called and why are they missing the second dimension? I'm on OSX and Ubuntu - not sure if that makes a difference.

Example:

```
>>> import torch
>>> a=torch.randn(1)
>>> a

 2.1358
[torch.FloatTensor of size 1]

>>> a.size()
(1L,)
>>> a=torch.randn(1).size()
>>> a
(1L,)
```

Comment: For me `torch.randn(1).size()` yields `torch.Size([1])`. No empty dimension there...

Comment: @blckbird I just updated the post with an example

Comment: Intressting. Which PyTorch version are you using? Do you only have this with 1-dimensional tensors?

Answer (score 1):

It is not a pytorch specific. This convention is followed in python as well. Let a vector of size (5,) and a matrix of size (5,1) is different. Although they have the same number of elements.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a=np.random.rand(5)
>>> a.shape
>>> (5,)

>>> b=np.random.rand(5,1)
>>> (5,1)
```